# How can I build an installer for a single data file?

Tags: macos, install, pkg

I need to install a single file in `~/Library/Spelling/voikko/`, and I want to use Apple's software for it, to get signing and all that stuff correct.

Problem is, so far I have found no way of installing a single file. All options and solutions assume you are installing a bundle.

I need an installer since the `~/Library/` dir is hidden - it is too much to ask regular users to open that dir, find the correct subdir, and then create another dir manually.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: What happens if you add another unnecessary file? Or even just a 'read me' file or 'release notes' file?

Comment: @Monomeeth: This is the command I tried: `pkgbuild --component sma.zhfst --install-location ~/Library/Spelling/`. And the error message I got was: `pkgbuild: error: Path "/Users/xxx/sma.zhfst" is not a valid bundle component (using destination path "/Users/xxx/")`

Comment: I don't think adding another file will help, as long as they are not organised in a bundle structure.